# Narrow centered single frame in tmux

Tags: tmux, gnu-screen, pane

Writing prose in a console environment I like to have my editor in a narrow centered pane. I can achieve this with this .screenrc:

```
focusminsize 75 25
split -v
focus
only
split -v
split -v
focus
caption string "%{= dd} "
sorendition "="
```

Then `$screen emacs` gives me the desired layout.

How do I achieve something similar in tmux 1.8?

Bonus: how to I bind toggling 'default layout' / 'narrow centered single pane' to a key?